# No desktop display

Tags: 14.04, graphics, lubuntu, display

I upgraded 12.04 lubuntu to 14:04. There was no desktop so I downloaded nautilus. The display now shows

> gtk-warning cannot open display

What do I need to do to get my desktop working?

Comment: please provide more info. Can you login and see desktop?